# need a good edge detection procedure for rough surfaced overlapped objects

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I need to detect edge for shape detection in my project.
Currently i am using MATLAB but i am comfertable with openCV if it gives better output.
So here is the problem. The sample image that i have has overlapped objects with rough surface.
I am using this code and getting a good output but the roughness of surface still makes my degrades my output.
I amusing this code in MATLAB:

```
a = imread('D:\images\wheatstarch.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(a);
imshow(I)
thresold = graythresh(I);
se1=strel('diamond',2);
I1=imerode(I,se1);
bw = edge(I1,'canny'); 
figure;
imshow(bw);
```

I am getting this output: 
http://i49.tinypic.com/vg7fns.png

Ineed a better output such that i can use the output for shape detection.

input image for download
http://www.profimedia.si/photo/wheat-starch-granules/profimedia-0035237439.jpg

Comment: what do you mean by "better output"? Can you provide resulting images for "better output"??

Comment: i mean it should be no extra zigzag line or excessive lines that have been detected due to shadows on the surface or due to shadows by  overlapping object.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the file in photoshop, the photoshop find edges edges followed by a levels command gives an output much more like you are looking for. I'm not suggesting you use photoshop, photoshop is a handy tool for visualizing methods to process graphics files. I always write my own code, so can't suggest any off the shelf solution.

What I'm seeing is photoshop's find edges gives a grayscale result of the edge hardness and the objects you are looking for are the ones with the hardest edges.

What it appears that you are getting is the image first converted to b&w (like the level command), then finding the edges. The conversion to b&w is creating arbitrary lines in shadows, which are then being traced. This is resulting in what appears in the original image as a smooth transition of grays in a shadow into an artificial line in the tracing.

By creating the edges in grayscale, then converting the grayscale edges to b&w, the smooth shifts of gray do not produce any edges.

Answer (score 0):

You better take a look at [BSDS](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html) they have state-of-the-art edge detection that should perform much better than Canny.
They also have source code (matlab compiled for Linux).